# I got error C2296 and C3867 when I tried to overload operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I want to overload operators( as free functions) for working with fractions but got some errors(23). My intuition is telling me that problem with const or smth like that. It's a little bit complicated for me now. So how to fix this or get this theme better?

- Error    C2296   '*': illegal, left operand has type 'int (__thiscall

          Rational::* )(void) const'
- Error    C2297   '*': illegal, right operand has type 'int (__thiscall    Rational::* )(void) const'
- Error    C3867   'Rational::Denominator': non-standard syntax; use '&' to    create a pointer to member

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int GetGsd(int a, int b) {      // Greatest common divisor
    while (a > 0 && b > 0) {
        if (a > b) {
            a = a % b;
        }
        else {
            b = b % a;
        }
    }
    return a + b;
}

char GetSignOfFraction(int a, int b) {
    if (a >= 0 && b > 0 || a <= 0 && b < 0) {
        return '+';
    }
    else if (a < 0 || b < 0) {
        return '-';
    }
}

class Rational {    // default c
public:
    Rational() {
        num = 0;
        den = 1;
    }

    Rational(const int numerator, const int denominator) {    
        num = numerator / GetGsd(numerator, denominator);
        den = denominator / GetGsd(numerator, denominator);
    }
    Rational& operator=(const Rational& r) {  // overloaded = 
        Rational a{ r.num,r.den };
        return a;
    }


    int Numerator() const {
        char sign = GetSignOfFraction(num, den);
        if (sign == '+') {
            return  fabs(num / GetGsd(num, den));
        }
        else {
            return num / GetGsd(num, den);
        }

    }

    int Denominator() const {
        if (num == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        return fabs(den / GetGsd(num, den));
    }

private:
    int num;
    int den;
};

Rational operator+(const Rational& lhs, const Rational& rhs) { // overloaded +   // problem is there
    Rational a;
    a.Denominator = rhs.Denominator * lhs.Denominator;
    a.Numerator = rhs.Numerator * lhs.Denominator + lhs.Numerator * rhs.Denominator;

    a.Numerator /= GetGsd(a.Numerator, a.Denominator);
    a.Denominator /= GetGsd(a.Numerator, a.Denominator);
    return a;

}

bool operator==(const Rational& lhs, const Rational& rhs) {  // and there
    if (lhs.Numerator == rhs.Numerator && lhs.Denominator == rhs.Denominator) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}



int main()
{

}
```

Comment: the error messages should contain the line numbers, please indicate them in the code

Comment: How would `a.Denominator = rhs.Denominator * lhs.Denominator` work when `Denominator` is a ***function***? Do you mean `a.den = rhs.den * lhs.den`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  Oh, I forget to do getter or did data public, tnx

Comment: Turn on all your compiler warnings.  This code has a plethora of bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are *several* problems with your code here.

You are getting the errors from this line and the lines immediatly after it

```cpp
a.Denominator = rhs.Denominator * lhs.Denominator;
```

There are two main problems here.

1. You are trying to assign the value of a member *method* instead of calling it
2. Even if you called it you are trying to assign a value to a returned **`const`**`int`

You can solve the first issue by simply adding brackets to the method call `a.Denominator()`, however the second error is more complex. If you want to change the value of a.den (which I think is what your trying to do) you will need to write a second acessor which can be used for setting the value.

```cpp
void Denominator(int denominator){
        den = denominator
}
```

Then call it with `a.Denominator(/* My new value of a.den */)`